# How to restore checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one buton on my jsp and clicking that button user will see jquery dialog box as popup,which is having several checkboxes.
That popup will also have two button save and cancel.

I would like to restore state of checkbox.for better understading please follow below steps

1. user clicks on showpop button on the jsp page
2. user will now see jquery popup having several checkbox
3. user checks first and second checkbox from the popup and click on save button that result in closing popup
4. user again click on show popup button ,uncheck first check box and click on cancel button that also result in closing popup
5. and now from main jsp if user again clicks on show popup buton i would like to see two checkbox  checked but its showing one checkbox checked.

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Save checkbox states in cookies.

Comment: Do you want to save the data on the client side or the server?  If on the client, consider using localStorage or cookies with a jQuery plugin like https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

Comment: Thanks for reply..i would like to store client side.i will give it a try

Comment: You can serialize the form when the user clicks showpop and store that in a javascript variable.  If the user clicks cancel, you can deserialize the form with a plugin like https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize

Answer (score 4):

you can use a variable to store the indices of the checked boxes on the page such as:

```
var checkedIndices = [];
```

when you click save or cancel, you can run some code similar to this:

```
function SaveBoxes() {
    checkedIndices = [];

    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, checkbox) {
        if ($(checkbox).is(":checked")) 
            checkedIndices.push($(checkbox).index());
    });
}

function CancelBoxes() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");

    for (i = 0; i < checkedIndices.length; i++)
        $("input[type=checkbox]:eq(" + checkedIndices[i] + ")").attr("checked", "checked");
}
```